# Modify WebInitParam in Servlet 3.0 when the project in packaged in a WAR

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

In my project I'm using Servlet 3.0 and I've tried to use annotations.

To init the connection parameters for the DB I use this in my servlet :

```
@WebServlet(name = "FrontServlet", urlPatterns = {"/index"},
        initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name = "userDB", value = "root"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "passwordDB", value = "*****")})
```

Now when I packaged the project in a WAR I've no web.xml  so I can't edit the init parameters as I used to do whith older servlet version.

My question is, can I edit my init parameters when the project is packaged in a WAR? If yes how? Otherwise what approach should I use to store my init parameters and be able to modify them in the WAR?

If possible I would like to avoid to recreate the whole web.xml with all URL-patterns, etc...

EDIT :

Finally I kept :

```
@WebServlet(name = "FrontServlet", urlPatterns = {"/index"})
```

And I load DB params using [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), accessing the config file with `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("servlet/config/config.ini")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no standard way to modify the init params in runtime. Moreover, it's a bad practice to put configuration there, especially to put there database credentials in a clear text.

Usually the best practices is to put a configuration in an external file. It may be some custom properties or xml file.

For database connection it's common to use JNDI. So basically in the code you look for a JNDI resource, while the JNDI itself in configured at container level. Google to find a lot of examples how to configure database connection via JNDI for Jetty, Tomcat, JBoss and more.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, just to clarify, I don't need to change anything at runtime. Just in the WAR before deployement.

Comment: Think about it like this: even you want to change the war before the deployment where the info will come from? Another file? So put this file aside the war and reference it from the war. As I said usually JNDI is a convenient way to do this, but there are more options.

Comment: Ok, finally I took the config file option. JNDI sounds like a good idea but I've never used it so I keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

In Servlet 3.0 the annotations provide the defaults but these can be over-ridden in web.xml so you can add the following to web.xml to change the paramaters.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FrontServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fully.qualified.ClassName</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>passwordDB</param-name>
      <param-value>NewValue</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

In Tomcat at least, you need to specify the class name and the Servlet name. Without looking into the merging code further (it is a while since I worked on it) one of those should be sufficient. For now, you'll need to use both.

Comment: If I use the web.xml, my annotations won't work anymore, I've resolve the problem using a config file in my war. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Wrong. The annotations and the contents of web.xml are merged, with web.xml taking priority. Read section 8 of the Servlet 3 specification or details Or just try it.

Comment: Ok I see but it's the same as storing all in the web.xml, it's not really conveniant. I've preffered avoiding the web.xml and use a properties file instead.

Comment: It is not the same as storing it all in web.xml. The point is that you can use web.xml to override *just* the annotations you want to edit. You'll note, for example, that the url pattern is not in web.xml. The value from the annotation is used. If you prefer a properties file then fine. Personally, I loathe annotations. They make it much, much harder for system admins to figure out what on earth is going on.

Comment: Yes it's not the same but in my case only urlpatterns stay in annotations... that's why I said that. But your right I ve tried annotations to see how it works but eventually the old web.xml is easier to administrate ;) thanks for explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Although you found a workaround using `getClassLoader`, it is not a Servlet approach.
Also, using `web.xml` just for the sake of configuring parameters that are already defined by `WebInitParam` and `WebServlet`, is very combersome, because you are forced to duplicate the server name, url-pattern and class location.

**But fortunately there is a Servlet solution that currently isn't mentioned on this page.**

You can use a `ServletContextListener` to programmatically add servlet init params without having to alter the original servlet. (As long as the servlet uses servlet init params to get values.) This is a solution without having to use `web.xml`.

The ServletContextListener:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletParamInitializer implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contentEvent) {
        ServletRegistration servletRegistration = contentEvent.getServletContext().getServletRegistration("MyServlet");
        servletRegistration.setInitParameter("userDB", "root");
        servletRegistration.setInitParameter("passwordDB", "*****");
    }
}
```

So it uses `ServletRegistration` to set the init params.

The servlet can then access the init params from the `ServletConfig` that is only available for this Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", value = "/*", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // You could use this method to do some db initialization
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        String userDB = config.getInitParameter("userDB");
        System.out.println("MyServlet.init(): userDB=" + userDB);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

        String userDB = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("userDB");
        String message = "MyServlet.doGet(): userDB=" + userDB;
        System.out.println(message);
        writer.println(message);

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```